# Downloading a file from a column in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created an SSRS Report which has a column named `Attachment` which I want to display a link that, when clicked downloads the appropriate attachment

I have used this procedure which is accepting different parameters:

```
alter proc [dbo].[getLessonLearntDetails_New_Test]
@AssetID nvarchar(50),
@DepartmentID varchar(50),
@Category varchar(50),
@AuditType varchar(50),
@AuditStartYear nvarchar(50),
@AuditEndYear nvarchar(50)

as
begin
select row_number() over(order by AssetName asc) as Sno
      ,LLD.LessonComputedID
      ,tbl_Asset.AssetName
      ,AT.AuditType
      ,SY.Year+' - '+EY.Year as 'Audit Period'
      ,DE.DepartmentName
      ,CT.CategoryName
      ,LLD.Learnings
      ,LLD.RepeatedObservationReference
      ,Att.Attachment
from tbl_LessonLearntDetails as LLD
    inner join tbl_Category as CT
        on CT.CategoryID = LLD.Title
    inner join tbl_Asset
        on LLD.AssetID = tbl_Asset.AssetID
    inner join tbl_Department as DE
        on LLD.DepartmentID = DE.DepartmentID
    inner join tbl_AuditType as AT
        on LLD.AuditTypeID = AT.AuditTypeID
    inner join tbl_Attachment as Att
        on LLD.LessonLearntID = Att.LeassonLearntID
    inner join tbl_AuditYear as SY
        on SY.Year = LLD.AuditStartYear
    inner join tbl_AuditYear as EY
        on EY.Year = LLD.AuditEndYear
where ( (('0'=@AssetID and (1=1)) or LLD.AssetID=@AssetID) and 
        (('0'=@DepartmentID and (1=1)) or LLD.DepartmentID=@DepartmentID) and
        (('0'=@Category and (1=1)) or LLD.Title=@Category) and
        (('0'=@AuditType and (1=1)) or LLD.AuditTypeID=@AuditType) and
        (('0'=@AuditStartYear and (1=1)) or (lld.AuditStartYear between @AuditStartYear and @AuditEndYear or lld.AuditEndYear between @AuditEndYear and @AuditStartYear) and
        (('0'=@AuditEndYear and (1=1)) or lld.AuditEndYear between @AuditEndYear and @AuditStartYear or lld.AuditEndYear between @AuditStartYear and @AuditEndYear))
    )
end
```

Comment: You could have a page that downloads a document according to a param from the URL and then have the report navigate there after clicking.

Comment: I am new to SSRS so I need more guidence on how it canbe done. Hope you'll help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this solution after some experiments and it definitely works for me. I assume that you will have a "**DisplayName**" for your attachment and then the full path of the file and extension. Set your Textbox column to "**DisplayName**"  of the attachment, then right click on the attachment Textbox, then -> Action -> "Go to URL" then on the expression type the following:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Replace(Fields!AttachmentLink.Value, "", "\") & "','_blank'))"
```

This will download/open the file in  a new tab.
Please see the below screenshot:
[image]

also, make sure to make the textbox look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a link openable by URL, you can go to Textbox Properties -> Action -> Go To URL -> Select URL and do an expression and put something like this in:

="javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!GoToThisURL.Value & "', '_blank'))"

Fields!GoToThisURL.Value would be the full URL value you want to go to include the .pdf extension I would think.